# Target Firefox Desktop CSS

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, firefox

I'd like to target the desktop version of Firefox only (not the Android mobile version) with the following CSS properties:

```
.background {
    background: url(imagelocation) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I'm trying to create a parallax effect with multiple divs (widths set to 100% and height set to XXXpx) and the background image are fixed while the nested divs scroll out of view.

Here is an example of my codepen: http://cdpn.io/AdglB

When you view this on Firefox Mobile for Android, it creates the effect but it slows down the scroll rendering - hence I would only like to target Firefox desktop if possible. This also creates other issues on the iPhone and Android in terms of background image scaling (it zooms all the way into a large image).

Answer (score 0):

Targetting only Firefox and no other browser: `@-moz-document url-prefix() {}`. It's a hack. Hacks are bad. Last resort.

Targetting desktop and not mobile: what about using Media Queries and the typical width of a desktop (or mobile) screen?

I guess if it's only about performance on mobile (all smartphones), then just use a MQ...